# Mouse Move application add command line arguments to auto start when windows starts

Tags: command-line, command-line-arguments, mousemove

I have the application 
http://movemouse.codeplex.com/

and I want to launch the app at startup (which I can do) but I also want to automatically hit the "Start" button so it turns on as soon as windows starts.

I need to have command line options to do this.

Anyone know of a command line option to do this?  And/or a command line list of options available for this program?

Thank You

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "automatically hit the start button, so it turns on a soon as windows starts". When you either include it in the `program folder startup` or in the various `registry keys`, the program will start as soon as windows starts. I don't know if you can run this before logon (just like a service).

Comment: If you want your MouseMover to do something extra, then you might be better off writing it (only a few lines in AutoHotKey which can be compiled to MouseMover.exe)

Comment: There is a "start button" on the application when it loads on startup, this button is not clicked automatically and I need to find a way to do it from the command line I am assuming, so I can just stat my PC and it will automatically start (and run) the mousemove application

Answer (score 2):

From looking at the settings, there are three options, that have to be set:

1. Automatically start Move Mouse on LAUNCH (same as press start when Move Mouse is opened)
2. Automatically launch Move Mouse at Windows LogOn
3. Minimize on start

I assume that the options work as presented.

[image]

Otherwise, as said before writing your own MouseMover in AutoHotKey is easy. and compiling it to an exe is easy too.

Here is some AutoHotKey code:

```
#Persistent
#SingleInstance force
SetTimer MoveMyMouse, 60000 ; 1000 ms = 1 sec.
Return

MoveMyMouse:
    MouseMove, 1, 0, 1, R ;Move the mouse one pixel to the right
    MouseMove, -1, 0, 1, R ;Move the mouse back one pixel
Return

^!#Pause::ExitApp
```

Load the code in AutoHotKey and test it, once your'e happy compile to your own MouseMove.exe

What is does:
During startup it starts a timer that executes the little sub-routine labeled MoveMyMouse every 60 seconds. This little sub-routine will move your mouse one pixel back and forth.

I also added an escape by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Pause</kbd>.

Comment: @Brad Please provide feedback on the proposed solution. When the answer was helpful, please "Accept" the answer by clicking on the WHITE "Check-mark" next to the answer, to turn it GREEN. Thank you! Clicking the check-mark will give credits to the person who submitted the answer and will mark the question as answered. See: [Accepting answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/210367)

Answer (score 0):

create a cmd file that starts your app and sends a key press to either the left or right "Windows" keys

**triggering the windows key will open the start menu**

to trigger the windows key, you need to download [nircmd.zip](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.zip) and unzip its folder somewhere, then cd the path to that folder

**paths may be case sensitive**

```
start "C:\path-to-your-apps\app-name.exe"
cd "C:\path-to-nircmd-folder\"
nircmd sendkey lwin press
```

**do not run your app on startup**

instead run the cmd file on startup

to run the cmd file on startup, you first need to make a desktop shortcut to it.

**do not right click cmd file > create shortcut**

right click the cmd file > send to > desktop (create shortcut)

a window should appear
place the following into the browse field

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C "C:\path-to-cmd-folder\cmd-name.cmd"
```

name the shortcut then press the enter key

next, right click your new desktop shortcut > properties
navigate to shortcut tab
set "Run" to "Minimized" so you don't see the command prompt pop up as it runs your cmd file

finally, copy or move your shortcut into your startup folder

```
"C:\Windows\User\your-user-name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
```